# why can't I get a checkpoint to flash with a script?

Tags: roblox

I am trying really hard to start with a simple skeleton on Roblox Studio, and then change one of the checkpoints (or all of them) so that they flash.

I thought to do that by using a script that I saw online that changes the transparency from 1 to 0 and back every 1 second.

So I tried this (I added this to all Checkpoints quite consistently in the same way):

[image]

and this (for this one I just added the part at the bottom):

[image]

but whenever I played in the Studio to test it I always got static checkpoints:

[image]

It is either the script is not running, or transparency is not the right way to go or what?

Comment: Heyo, please don't share pictures of your code. Pictures are great for showing your Workspace structure and the problem you're experiencing, but it makes it difficult for us to work with your code. Could you please share your code as text?

Answer (score 1):

The "Checkpoints" folder has many objects in it that are called "Checkpoint". If you want to flash a particular one from its child script, you could do this instead:

```
while (true) do
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
    wait(1)
    script.Parent.Transparency = 0
    wait(1)
end
```

it will only flash its parent (the Checkpoint).

Comment: You could also name each one seperately (such as Checkpoint1, Checkpoint2, etc.) and refer to those ones individually.